# Why :first-child don't effect the class child

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an HTML like this:

```html
<div class="cards-container">
 <div class="project-container">
      <section class="project-text-container">Text</section>
      <section class="project-content-container">Content</section>
 </div>
  <div class="project-container">
      <section class="project-content-container">Content</section>
      <section class="project-text-container">Text</section>
 </div>
</div>
```

and a Scss:

```css
.project-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);

    section {
        &:first-child {
            margin-inline-end: 0.75rem;
        }
        &:last-child {
            margin-inline-start: 0.75rem;
        }
    }

    .project-content-container {
    }

     &:first-child .project-text-container {
        margin-block-start: 10rem;
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

I want that the first ".project-container" have a ".project-text-container" different.
But it doesn't change, and Idk why!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89vtE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your syntax. I have tested in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/462zkmvj/) and the first .project-container child shows a background-color and margin.

```
 <div class="project-container">
      <section class="project-text-container">First</section>
      <section class="project-content-container">Content</section>
 </div>
  <div class="project-container">
      <section class="project-text-container">Second</section>
      <section class="project-content-container">Content</section>
 </div>

.project-container {

  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;

  &:first-child .project-text-container {
    background-color: #fc0;
    margin-block-start: 50px;
  }
}
```

Have you tested with other CSS properties (such as background-color, which is easier to detect)?

Comment: A put a background-color for testing, but don't work as well.
(note: the other styles are working, I put a `display: grid;   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);` at the "project-container" It works! If I put a style at ".project-text-container" or ".project-content-container" the shows normally as it should be.